npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
I am encountering an issue when running npm install on my Ubuntu server. It works fine on my local environment (Windows/macOS), but on the server, the installation fails with the following error:
npm ERR! TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
This error occurs during the package installation process. The error log shows the issue happens when trying to extract certain packages.


Environment Details:
Local Environment:

OS: Windows 11
Node.js version: 18.20.5
npm version: 10.2.3

Server Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Node.js version: 18.20

Full error
pm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-12-17T11_59_28_172Z-debug-0.log
root@zotac31870:~/zota-cpos-backend-ts# npm i
npm WARN tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated fstream@1.0.12: This package is no longer supported.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142


npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global run this command, it seems like the issue with npm registery

Changing the registry to registry.npmjs.org with this command:
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global

worked for us.

@GeneralGrievance This is slightly different than the other answer, the repository link is registry.npmjs.org, rather than registry.npmmirror.com
